# UITableViewDelegate not being called

Tags: ios

I am trying to call a detail screen from a UITableView list - but the delegate is not being called in the receiving view - I'll post all the code:

list header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "tank.h"

@class iTanksV2ListViewController;
@protocol iTanksV2ListViewControllerDelegate
     - (void) iTanksListViewController:(iTanksV2ListViewController *) sender choseTank:(tank *)tank;
@end

@interface iTanksV2ListViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tanks;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tankTableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <iTanksV2ListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

and the m file:

```
#import "iTanksV2ListViewController.h"
#import "tank.h"
#import "tankDetailViewController.h"

@interface iTanksV2ListViewController () 

@end

@implementation iTanksV2ListViewController
@synthesize tanks = _tanks;
@synthesize tankTableView = _tankTableView;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this    view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTankTableView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;//keep this section in case we do need to add sections in the future.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.tanks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Tank List Table Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tankTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    }
    tank *thisTank = [self.tanks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = thisTank.tankNumber;
    return cell;
}

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Tank Details"])
    {

    }
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    tank *thisTank = [self.tanks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.delegate iTanksListViewController:self choseTank:thisTank];

}

@end
```

and the header for the receiving file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "tankGauge.h"
#import "tank.h"

@interface tankDetailViewController : UIViewController 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tankNumberLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tankProductLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tankAvailableProductLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tankMaxVolumeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet tankGauge *tankVolumeGauge;
@property (weak, nonatomic)  tank* tankToShow;
@end
```

...and the m file:

```
#import "tankDetailViewController.h"
#import "iTanksV2ListViewController.h"

@interface tankDetailViewController () <iTanksV2ListViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation tankDetailViewController
@synthesize tankNumberLabel = _tankNumberLabel;
@synthesize tankProductLabel = _tankProductLabel;
@synthesize tankAvailableProductLabel = _tankAvailableProductLabel;
@synthesize tankMaxVolumeLabel = _tankMaxVolumeLabel;
@synthesize tankVolumeGauge = _tankVolumeGauge;
@synthesize tankToShow = _tankToShow;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)iTanksListViewController:(iTanksV2ListViewController *)sender choseTank:(id)tank
{
    self.tankToShow = tank;
   self.tankNumberLabel.text = self.tankToShow.tankNumber;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setTankNumberLabel:nil];
    [self setTankProductLabel:nil];
    [self setTankAvailableProductLabel:nil];
    [self setTankMaxVolumeLabel:nil];
    [self setTankVolumeGauge:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tankTableView` is an `IBOutlet`, so you just need to connect your tableView's delegate and data-source to your `File's Owner` in your `xib` as shown below:
[image]

Comment: I have just checked and I think this is done - the delegate and datasource are both set to itanksv2listviewcontroller :-S is that correct?

Comment: Absolutely! Are you setting them programmatically or through `xib`?

Comment: They are being set through the storyboard I think! I am new to this and it seems v complicated at the moment! :-S

Comment: If you're not sure, I'd suggest you do it programmatically too. `tankTableView.delegate=self;` and `tankTableView.dataSource=self;`

Comment: I have sorted it i think. The problem may just have been that the Identifier for the tableviewrowcell hadn't been reset after changing it... :-S oops!!! Thank you for your help anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set that viewcontroller as the delegate for that tableview?

Comment: I think so! In the implementation of the view controller - the last piece of code in the view...